# Socket communication with GPRS Printers through remote web server

Tags: sockets, printing, port, gprs

I have a GPRS Printer, similar to the printers that iBacsTel is selling (http://www.ibacstel.com), that is going to receive order messages from another device (could be from a website or app) via a server.

This printer receives order messages by listening to one of the port of the server it can be assigned to, like 5000. If there are several other printers as well every one of them needs to be assigned as well to one individual port like 5001, 5002, 5003 etc...

From what I understand I need to use Socket Communication in order to establish connection between a computer device and a GPRS printer and my idea was that I send the order message from the computer device to a remote server, which can be accessed by the web domain name, and then the right individual printer receives it, which is determined by the assigned port it is listened to.

Now, the problem is that from what I have read so far about socket communication that you can only send message to a remote server to the port 80 and you cannot listen to a remote server on any of the ports at all (5000, 5001 and so on). But instead you need to have a local server instead in order for the printers to listen for incoming order messages.
And that would mean that the computer devices and the printers must reside in the same area as the local server which is not my intention. My idea is that it is going to work as the same as this order taking system https://www.gloriafood.com/online-ordering

So how do I establish this kind of communication that you can see on that order taking system like Gloria Food?

Comment: What language and technology are you using?  You seem to be confusing *Websockets* with network sockets.  They are not the same thing.  Also, **always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Comment: As I am programming an app in both Android and iOS that represents the computer device that will send the order message to the server, Java and Objective-C are the languages that I use in this case.

I studied it further today and it seems that I could create a chat-server application in Java and somehow run it on a remote server that allows clients listen to any of the ports. But how you run a chat-server application on a remote server remains unanswered. 

The printer is configured that you input the IP-address to the server and which port of the server it will listen to.